# Add widget to the middle of a Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a blog at www.tosreport.com/scripting and might want to adjust where I place certain items such as the shoutbox plug-in on the right hand side of the page. Apparently, the only 'widget areas' are sidebar and footer.  Is it possible to place a widget in the body of a page or even in the body of a particular post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you just have to register another sidebar widget area:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

And then, place on index.php or loop.php depends on your theme layout:

Check this code, this is an example of what you need, placing the previous code in the "ad" code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7001372/1478479